# Compare two variables having multiple values in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I was trying my hand on shell script after a quite long time. Here it goes, if I have two variables say var & foo as below:

```
$ echo $var
root daemon bin sys sync games man lp mail news uucp proxy www-data backup list irc gnats nobody systemd-timesync systemd-network systemd-resolve systemd-bus-proxy syslog _apt lxd messagebus uuidd dnsmasq sshd zarvis

$ echo $foo
games backup nobody zarvis
```

They have some values in common and I want to compare them and find out only the unique values. So far I have tried a lot from the web but was unable to find the solution. Please help.

Comment: Can you add what you've tried thus far?  Also, please post your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all the items that are in `$var` that are **not** in `$foo`, this will do it:

```
tmp()
{
  var="root daemon bin sys sync games man lp mail news uucp proxy www-data backup list irc gnats nobody systemd-timesync systemd-network systemd-resolve systemd-bus-proxy syslog _apt lxd messagebus uuidd dnsmasq sshd zarvis"
  foo="games backup nobody zarvis"
  varray={$var}
  for v in ${varray[@]}
  do
    if ! [[ "$foo" =~ "$v" ]]; then
       echo "No match -- $v"
    fi
  done
}
```

If you want to find the items in `$foo` that are not in `$var` (the other way 'round), just switch the two in the above code.  If you want both lists, run one after the other.

Note: There may be a way to do both at the same time, but sometimes, in the real world, a solution that is quick and simple is preferable to one that is clever and complicated.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a ton bro ! There was a tiny mistake though 

`varray=($var)`   should be   `varray={$var}`

Rest all was fine.

Comment: Whups.  My apologies.  I will fix that in the answer.  Thanks!